# c: accept() for non-blocking server

Tags: c, sockets

I am writing a tcp server interface in C. In this interface, I would require to listen for command and send periodic outputs through the same sockets. I would think in this case I would need to program my sockets to be non-blocking. Here is my code

```
#define ERROR         -1
#define MAX_CLIENTS    2
#define MAX_DATA    1024

int setNonblocking(int fd)
{
    int flags;

#if defined(O_NONBLOCK)
    if (-1 == (flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0)))
        flags = 0;
    return fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
#else
    flags = 1;
    return ioctl(fd, FIOBIO, &flags);
#endif
} 

int main()
{
    int       lsock;                           
    struct    sockaddr_in saddr;  
    short int port;       
    char      buffer[MAX_DATA];
  
    int socketOption=1;
    int LISTENQ     =1;

    /// creating sockets
    if ( (lsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 )
    {
       printf(" Error: sockets creation \n");
       return -1;
    }

    memset(&saddr, 0, sizeof(saddr));
    saddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    saddr.sin_port        = htons(2222);

    setsockopt(lsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &socketOption, sizeof(socketOption));

    setNonblocking(lsock);

    if ( bind(lsock, (struct sockaddr *) &saddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ECHOSERV: Error calling bind()\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if ( listen(lsock, LISTENQ) < 0 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ECHOSERV: Error calling listen()\n");
        return -1;
     }

    bool running    = true;
    bool bConnected = true;
    while ( running )
    {
        int       csock; 
        time_t start = time(NULL);
        time_t now;             
        if ( (csock = accept(lsock, NULL, NULL) ) < 0 )
        {
            int errno_s = errno;
            printf("The error is %d \n", errno_s);
            fprintf(stderr, "ECHOSERV: Error calling accept()\n");
            return -1;
        } 
        else
        {
            bConnected  =true;
        }

        while(bConnected)
        {
           int n;
           if((n=recv(lsock, buffer, MAX_DATA, 0)) > 0)
           {
               printf("Command Handling \n");
           }

           if(now - start == 100)
           {
               printf("Data Sending \n");
           }

        }
    return 0;
}
```

The program always run into error whenever accept() is being called, I wonder why csock always return -1? I then tried to print out the errno. The errno read 11, which seems to be EAGAIN ( telling to try again ). So should I ignore this error?

I did think about other method to achieve what I want eg using select() and a set of file sockets... but somehow i think it might run into problem

Need your opinion and help on this

REgards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [accept](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) man page:

> If no pending connections are present on the queue, and the socket is not marked as nonblocking, `accept()` blocks the caller until a connection is present.  **If the socket is marked nonblocking and no pending connections are present on the queue,
> `accept()` fails with the error `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.**

You can use `select()` to test for data on a listening socket, and then call `accept()` only when it actually has data, ie a pending connection.

Comment: "*You can use `select()` ...*" - or `(e)poll()`, which is generally better to use, as it doesn't have the restrictions that `select()` has, such as a limited number of sockets it can test at a time.